# How to force Rider to build with dotnet?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, rider

My build server is building my .NET6 project with `dotnet build`. The build fails ([MSB3823](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/4704)) there but succeeds on my machine with Rider 2021.3.3. Running `dotnet build` from the command line gives me the same error, something intentionally changed for .NET Core, and `msbuild` succeeds. In an effort to diagnose the problem and sooner address future ones like it, how can I force Rider to use `dotnet` and not `msbuild`?

(essentially the opposite of [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-28474))

Edit: I have also tried checking/unchecking "Use Resharper Build"
[image]

Comment: You can try to go `Toolset and Build` settings page and uncheck "ReSharper Build" feature

Comment: Also ensure you have the same msbuild (and roslyn inside) on your local machine and on CI. You can switch msbuild and dotnet which Rider uses on the same settings page